# batch script to rename a file with string (with space) from variable

Tags: batch-file

There is a file named doctitle.txt which contains the title. I want to use this title to rename another file, currently name file.pdf, so I did:

```
for /f "delims=" %%x in (doctitle.txt) do set "DOCTITLE=%%x"
move file.pdf %DOCTITLE%.pdf
```

This works fine, if there no space in the title string, i.e "DocumentTitle". But fails if there is a space in the title, i.e "Document Title".

What could be done to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%x in (doctitle.txt) do set DOCTITLE=%%~x
move file.pdf "%DOCTITLE%.pdf"
```

That way, the variable `DOCTITLE` will not be surrounded with quotes as `%%~` removes any quotes.

Quoting `for /?`:

```
%~I         - expands %I removing any surrounding quotes (")
```

Comment: Let's say title is "açaí", then I want to use "acai" instead (replacing the accents). Would it be possible?

Comment: @oqrxke I'm not completely sure, but ask it as a different question so others can help

Comment: Thanks! I've posted a new question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31195236/batch-scritp-to-replace-accents-in-words.